# Hibernate with NVARCHAR2

Tags: hibernate, oracle11g, hibernate-mapping, nvarchar

I have table with a column as `NVARCHAR2`, and I have build my object with hibernate annotations, When i want to insert into DB or fetch from DB the result is something like that "???????",
I have implemented a custom Dialect as follows but it did not work.

```
public class CustomOracleDialect extends Oracle10gDialect{

    public CMSCustomOracleDialect() {
        registerHibernateType( Types.NVARCHAR, Hibernate.STRING.getName() );
        registerColumnType( Types.VARCHAR, "nvarchar2($1)" );
        registerColumnType( Types.CLOB, "nclob" );
        registerColumnType( Types.NCLOB, "nclob" );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Might be a little late but I have just come across this issue aswell and I found that can annotate your hibernate class with

```
@Nationalized
```

or

```
@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.StringNVarcharType")
```

which makes your element use `org.hibernate.type.StringNVarcharType` instead of the VarChar type string

which was introduced into hibernate in release 4.1.10 and above. So that it correctly uses the `NVarChar2` type or else it will default back to VarChar2 which then looses your international characters.

Hibernate Jira where this was resolved: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5869

And Jboss-Hibernate Documentation:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch08.html#value-national-character-types

Comment: You're the man. I used the property <property name="hibernate.use_nationalized_character_data" value="true"/> and that resolved my issues.

Answer (score 3):

How are you mapping your columns in the object? The below mappings works

```
@Column(name = "PHONE_NUMBER", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "nvarchar2 (2000)")
public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return this.phoneNumber;
}
```

Note this is JPA @Column annotation. Calling entityManager.persist() on the phone object works.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CustomOracleDialect extends Oracle10gDialect {

    public CustomOracleDialect() {
        super();
        registerColumnType(Types.NVARCHAR, "nvarchar2($l)");//$l not $1
        registerHibernateType(Types.NVARCHAR, StandardBasicTypes.STRING.getName());
    }
}
```

Then set `CustomOracleDialect` to your hibernate configuration file.